# Django : export table in file SQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, deployment, web-hosting

I try to deploy my website developped with Django 1.9. I use the web hosting AlwaysData.

The problem is that the database of my web hosting is empty (no tables) and I want to import my tables (in models.py) in this database.

For that, I need a file sql that contains all my tables. After I will import this file in my AlwaysData database.

I try the command dumpdata but the format sql doesn't exist (only yaml, xml and json).

How can I do ?

I use PostGreSQL.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would think that you could build your database using `./manage.py makemigrations` and then `./manage.py migrate`. However, if that does not work for you, it sounds like you want the [`sqlmigrate` management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#sqlmigrate):

```
./manage.py sqlmigrate my_app my_migration > my_migration.sql
```

This will generate the SQL for your migration, and redirect it to a file called `my_migration.sql`.